# How do I take C programming beyond the console?

Tags: c, graphics, image, console

I'm trying to learn some graphics programming using C.  What would be the best way for a beginner to start?  I'd like to how to make programs that use graphics and images that can be run directly from a command line prompt, and don't rely on a windowing system like X to execute.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: It's a platform-specific question, although there are some cross-platform libraries for this.

Comment: What platform? What sort of graphics do you want to do? 2D, 3D? Do you want to be writing low-level image processing, or high-level vector graphics? And by running from a command prompt, do you mean you just want to output images into files instead of displaying them directly on the screen?

Comment: I'm programming on Ubuntu Linux.  I'm thinking just 2D graphics for now, just to learn the ropes.  I'd probably try to make some graphical style menu using graphics I create in Photoshop or GIMP.  When I say running from a command line I mean programming it in a way that wouldn't require being run inside a windowing system, like Swing or Windows Forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into [libsdl - Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/).  Although on Linux it can use X11 for displaying output, it can also directly use a framebuffer device.  It's designed to be simple for pixel-bashing game-type programming, and supports a wide variety of platforms.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Allegro](http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/) if you're not a fan of SDL. It's somewhat more fully-featured for simple vector graphics; SDL is mainly a cross-platform framebuffer until you add extension libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Learn some GUI toolkit like Qt or GTK, this way you will make modern GUI applications.

Comment: he specifically said he didn't want to require a windowing system like X

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) GUI toolkit. It is small and easy to learn.